# Calculate z values with data from multiple csv files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DataFrames such as the following.

DataFrame one (df1):This is the file where the daily mean and std(standard deviation) are available with daily mood.

```
date    mood      score    count     mean         std       abs
5/1/16  positive  1003.3015 2205    0.45501202  0.1948684  1003.3015
6/1/16  negative  -956.2049 2012    -0.4752509  0.19673153 956.2049
7/1/16  positive  952.049   2095    0.45443866  0.19968715 952.049
8/1/16  neutral    10.021   20       0.50105    0.19613942 10.021
9/1/16  positive  715.7656  1528    0.46843298  0.19674478 715.7656
10/1/16 positive  802.8556  1643    0.48865222  0.20401112 802.8556
```

DataFrame Two (df2): File where I want to get the Z value [df2[score]-df1[mean]]/df1[std] in

```
date    score   mood
5/1/16  0.7089  positive
6/1/16  -0.6709 negative
7/1/16  0.564   positive
7/1/16  0.4078  positive
7/1/16  -0.2009 negative
8/1/16  0.0032  neutral
```

So what I want to basically get is the Z value for each of the rows in DataFrame Two. To do that, I have to **get the mean and std from df1**, **subtract the mean from the daily score in df2 and divide the resulting value by the std (standard deviation) in df2**. But the issue is df1 contains only one daily mood per date with their mean and std (basically it is an aggregate file) where df2 contains millions of rows and most of the dates have hundreds to thousands of scores with different moods.

**Expected Output**

```
date    score   mood         Zvalue 
5/1/16  0.7089  positive    1.30286892  
6/1/16  -0.6709 negative    -0.9944977  
7/1/16  0.564   positive    0.54866495  
7/1/16  0.4078  positive    -0.2335587  
7/1/16  -0.2009 negative     0         #because there is no negative mean or std value for this in df1
8/1/16  0.0032  neutral    -2.5382454
```

Having trouble to code it to get expected output. I would really appreciate some help here. If you could put some comments in steps, that would be super helpful.  Many thanks.

Comment: I can get expected `Zvalue` except for the 0. And I could not understand the comment. Could you elaborate on it so that I could post an answer matching all of your requirements? Or do you prefere an immediate even if partial answer?

Comment: @SergeBallesta the comment is saying that because there is no associated 'mean and std' for 'negative' mood in df1, it could not calculate the z value for that date. Let me know if it clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way with `merge` usage with parameter `how = 'left'` for merge `df1` and `df2` dataframes.

```
# step 1 set new index and get only mean and std columns from df1
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df1 = df1.set_index(['date','mood'])[['mean', 'std']]

df1
Out[1]:

                             mean   std
        date    mood        
    2016-01-05  positive    0.455012    0.194868
    2016-01-06  negative    -0.475251   0.196732
    2016-01-07  positive    0.454439    0.199687
    2016-01-08  neutral     0.501050    0.196139
    2016-01-09  positive    0.468433    0.196745
    2016-01-10  positive    0.488652    0.204011

# step 2
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
df2
Out[2]:

        date    score   mood
0   2016-01-05  0.7089  positive
1   2016-01-06  -0.6709 negative
2   2016-01-07  0.5640  positive
3   2016-01-07  0.4078  positive
4   2016-01-07  -0.2009 negative
5   2016-01-08  0.0032  neutral



# step 3: merge

df3 = df2.merge(df1, left_on = ['date','mood'], right_index = True, how = 'left')[['date','score','mood','std','mean']]

df3
Out[3]:

              date  score   mood         std        mean
   0    2016-01-05  0.7089  positive    0.194868    0.455012
   1    2016-01-06  -0.6709 negative    0.196732    -0.475251
   2    2016-01-07  0.5640  positive    0.199687    0.454439
   3    2016-01-07  0.4078  positive    0.199687    0.454439
   4    2016-01-07  -0.2009 negative    NaN         NaN
   5    2016-01-08  0.0032  neutral     0.196139    0.501050




df3['Zvalue'] = (df3['score']-df3['mean'])/df3['std']

df3[['date','score','mood','Zvalue']].fillna(0)
Out[4]:


         date   score   mood        Zvalue
0   2016-01-05  0.7089  positive    1.302869
1   2016-01-06  -0.6709 negative    -0.994498
2   2016-01-07  0.5640  positive    0.548665
3   2016-01-07  0.4078  positive    -0.233559
4   2016-01-07  -0.2009 negative    0.000000
5   2016-01-08  0.0032  neutral     -2.538245
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting the following error. KeyError: "['score_x'] not in index.

Comment: Hi! are you sure, that before you merge it, both of dataframe (df1 and df2) have 'score' column, like in your example on a top?

Comment: Ok, it doesn't matter, i have updated the code. check it again

Comment: Oh..damn..the score column on df1 had a named ['mean']. I was able to run the code. But the results are showing all 'Nan' values in zValue column. Is it an issue as I have not included one column in df1 in the question? wanted to reduce distraction.

Comment: hm) it's still little bit unclear for me. what columns df1 has in your source data? could you show  here  the df1.columns?

Comment: just edited the question with the extra column added back to df1.

Comment: that's work just fine for me. Pls check that you are using this updated code on 'step 1' and 'step 3' (see my comment in code)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208042/discussion-between-non-linear-and-alexey).